# Building a histogram in R

Tags: r, histogram

Good afternoon. Recently I've faced a problem with building histograms in R. I type:
`Hist_SP500hist<-hist(SP500logreturns,col="lightblue",breaks = 140, border="white",main="", xlab="Time",xlim=c(-0.001,0.001))`

Here I specify, that the number of breaks=140.
But when I type `Hist_SP500hist$breaks` I get 179 breaks.
How could it happen?

Comment: From `help('hist')`: *"the number is a suggestion only"*. Create a breakpoints sequence `brk<-seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = 140)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually adjust the breaks inside `hist` if you save it to an object.  Here is and example using the `faithful` dataset

Note: I don't have enough reputation to show the graphs the code produces

```r
waiting.hist <- hist(faithful$waiting)
```

edit: Since the breaks do not change the counts, you will have to update the counts too.  Otherwise the counts will be recycled

```r
waiting.hist$breaks <- seq(40, 100, 2.5)
waiting.hist$counts <- table(cut(faithful$waiting, seq(40, 100, 2.5)))

plot(waiting.hist)
```

Or you could use ggplot2 and specify the breaks using `bins` or `binwidth`

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tidyverse' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'tidyr' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'purrr' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'forcats' was built under R version 3.6.3
```

```r
faithful %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = waiting)) + 
  geom_histogram(bins = 30)
```

```r
faithful %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = waiting)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 2.5)
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>